# Is it possible for a new Recordset be created using a variable from an existing Recordset?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a Db for individuals to test on courses they have taken.  This Db takes input from an introduction form, selects data from a query, and passes it to the test form.  This works great (with many thanks to @xpofer) in that it returns questions randomly, but the answers are always in the same order.  This is because the tables and queries the Recordset is based on contains the following columns:

**TABLE**

ID

CDC

Vol

Question No (Randomized in query)

Section

Question

Ans A

Ans B

Ans C

Ans D

Correct Answer

What I am trying to do is not only present the questions randomly, but have the answers presented randomly also.  To do so, I have separated this into two separate tables.

**tblRnd_Ques**

ID (PK)

CDC

Vol

Question No

Section

Question

**tblRnd_Ans**

ID

Q_ID (FK)

Answer

Correct (Y/N)

Here are the queries I am trying to use.

**qryRnd_Ques**

ID

CDC

Vol

Question No.

Section

Question

Rnd_ID (Randomized ID, ascending)

**qryRnd_Ans**

Rnd_ID (Randomized ID, Ascending)

Q_ID

Answer

Correct (Y/N)

Now for the problem.  Is it possible to create a Recordset using a variable from a previous Recordset?  Here is the code I currently have:

```
Private Sub GetAnswers()

Dim rsAns As Recordset
Dim strAns As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim intQues As Long
Dim isCorr As Boolean

intQues = !ID

        strSQL = "Select [ID], [Answer], [Correct] FROM [qryRnd_Ans] WHERE [Q_ID] = " & intQues

        Set rsAns = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

        strAns = !Answer
        isCorr = !Correct

        MsgBox "Answer:  " & strAns _
        & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Correct:  " & isCorr

        rsAns.Close

End Sub
```

I have tried creating this second Recordset (rsAns) directly in the LoadNextQuestion sub where I now call GetAnswers.  I kept getting

> Run-time error 3464: Data type mismatch in criteria expression

with this code:

```
    strSQL = "Select [ID], [Answer], [Correct] FROM [qryRnd_Ans] WHERE [Q_ID] = '" & intQues & "'"

    Set rsAns = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
```

I figured I may need to place this code in a subroutine, hence the call to GetAnswers.  With this code, I get a Compile error:  Invalid or unqualified reference at the strAns = !Answer line.  I have searched many sites, including Microsoft, CNet, bytes.com, as well as Stackoverflow, and it appears as if the syntax is correct, so I am at a loss as to the problem.  Any assistance is appreciated.

UPDATE

After much sole- AND Internet searching, I found a solution.  I changed the variable values from strAns = !Answer to strAns = rsAns![Answer], and it all fell into place.  Many thanks to DanielG and the other sites I searched.

Comment: Is `Q_ID` a string or a number? If it's a number, which I am pretty sure it is, you dont put single quotes around it.

Comment: Yes, both Q_ID and intQues are numbers.  I have taken the single quotes out and still got error messages.  See my comment to DanielG for more info.

Comment: Please create a more minimal example. Around half your code and table structures aren't relevant to this problem. Read [how to create a complete,  minimal and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is an int, have you tried taking your single quotes out:

```
strSQL = "Select [ID], [Answer], [Correct] FROM [qryRnd_Ans] WHERE [Q_ID] = " & intQues
```

To get all of the answers in the recordset, you can now iterate the recordset:

```
If Not (rsANS.EOF And rsANS.BOF) Then
    Do Until rsANS.EOF = True
          ' Get the next answer and do something with it
          ' Me!MyTextBox = rsANS!MyNextAnswer 
    rsANS.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
```

Comment: Yes, I removed the single quotes, with continued error messages.  After racking my brain and even more searching, I found I needed to directly reference the first Recordset, i.e., strAns = rsAns![Answer].  This worked.  Now I need to return the next record in rsANS before exiting the subroutine. to get all possible answers to each question.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I modified the answer a bit. Is this what you need?

Comment: I changed up the code a bit.  Here is what I have now that seems to be doing what I need. `                With rsAns
 .MoveFirst
 Do Until .EOF
 
      strAns_ctl = "ctlAns_"
      strAnsNo = strAnsNo + 1
 
      strAns_ctl = strAns_ctl & strAnsNo
      strAns = rsAns![Answer]
     isCorr = rsAns!Correct
 
     MsgBox "Answer:  " & intAns & "    " & strAns _
     & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Correct:  " & isCorr _
     & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & strAnsNo
 
     strAnsNo = "strAns" & intAns
     intAns = intAns + 1
 
     .MoveNext
      Loop
 
     End With
`

Comment: Awesome. Glad it is working out